# How to wait for Task to complete before finishing function?

Tags: java, android, task

I've got function `getCoordinates()` to get location, it looks like this:

```
 public void getCoordinates(FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient){
        Task<Location> lastLocation = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();


        lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    lat = location.getLatitude() + "" ;
                    lon = location.getLongitude() + "";

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Right after calling `getCoordinates()` I need to call function `getCityName()`, which uses coordinates from previous function.

But because second function starts before first one finishes its task, my program doesn't work properly.

How is it possible to wait for `addOnSuccessListener` to complete and finish first function right after it, so the values are always initialized?

Comment: How about you call `getCityName` from `onSuccess` after setting the values . or you can create a Callback Interface .

Comment: Waiting for `addOnSuccessListener` to complete has no effect, since you effectively pass a callback funtion that is executed when the location is present. It is a _non-blocking_, _asyncronous_ behaviour. You can either emit an event that the coordinates are present or perform additional logic within `onSuccess`.

Answer (score 0):

try to call your second method getCityName() inside the onSuccess method.

Answer (score 0):

Just call your function inside the callback:

```
public void getCoordinates(FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient){
        Task<Location> lastLocation = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();


        lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    lat = location.getLatitude() + "" ;
                    lon = location.getLongitude() + "";
                    getCityName(lat,lon);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```